# How to bootstrap modal popup via a variable?

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, smarty

I am studying the bootstrap, and follow the example:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Shows the modal
</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                    &times;
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
                    模态框（Modal）标题
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                在这里添加一些文本
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">关闭
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                    提交更改
                </button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->
</div>
```

if I click the button the modal will popup, but I don't understand which variable is controlling the modal popup and disappear.

I want to through a variable to popup it. there is a requirement.

when I enter a Smarty page, if the page do not exists a access_token variable, I want the modal popup automatically.

So, how to realize in this example?

Comment: the modal pop up by the link at the button  data-target="#myModal"

Comment: is the access_token a cookie, or a php session varaible or what is it?

Comment: access_token is a cookie.

Comment: the id of the modal div is used for the controlling and targeting

Comment: @AmjadRehmanA How to use a variable control the modal show or dismiss?

Comment: data-target and data-toggle are the bootstrap javascript classes(we use them as an attribute in tags). they do the show/hide job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. With JavaScript (jQuery), select the modal element and store it in variable.
2. Trigger the show method.

   ```
   var myModal = $("#myModal");

   myModal.modal("show");
   ```

Comment: how a bout dismiss ?

Comment: Dismiss a modal with  myModal.modal ("hide"). Or, use the single shortcut command  myModal.modal("toggle") to show or hide the modal

Answer (score 0):

To show a modal:
 $('#myModal').modal('show');

To hide a modal:
 $('#myModal').modal('hide');